# Binomial sum identities

Tags: simplifying-expressions

How do you persuade Mathematica to give simple identities involving binomial sums. For example

```
Sum[Binomial[a,i]*Binomial[b,i],{i,0,n}]
```

where n is bigger than both a and b.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Assumptions.html) to get the result you expected.

```
In[1]:= $Assumptions = 
 n > a > 0 && n > b > 0 && a \[Element] Integers && b \[Element] Integers;


In[2]:= Sum[Binomial[a, i]*Binomial[b, i], {i, 0, n}]
Out[2]= Gamma[1 + a + b]/(Gamma[1 + a] Gamma[1 + b])

In[3]:= FullSimplify[%]
Out[3]= (a + b)!/(a! b!)
```

Note that it does give a generally valid result without these assumptions too.  Here the assumptions helped us obtain a simpler result.  I used the [`$Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/%24Assumptions.html) global variable here to avoid typing the assumptions twice, for `Sum` and `FullSimplify`.

Comment: Thank you. Out of interest, can it persuaded to give Binomial[a+b,a] as the output?

Comment: @Anush I don't know if it can do that automatically.  As you see, `FullSimplify` doesn't.

Comment: @Anush: If that particular result for this particular case is the desired end result, you can use something like `Assuming[n > a > 0 && n > b > 0 && {a, b} \[Element] Integers,
  FullSimplify[
   Sum[Binomial[a, i]*Binomial[b, i], {i, 0, 
     n}]]] /. (x_ + y_)!/(x_! y_!) :> Binomial[x + y, x]` to get it.